# How to create a folder inside uploads folder and store uploaded files there?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, upload

I want uploaded files to be stored in wp-content/uploads/example/

How to edit this code so this can be done?

```
$target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . 
    basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Right now, it uploads files to wp-content/uploads/2018/10

I tried:

```
 $target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
 $target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '../../example' . 
    basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

but it gives me file (uploadedfile.ext) uploaded in wp-content/uploads/2018 as exampleuploadedfile.ext

Comment: Maybe you can check this one, [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112226/how-to-save-media-files-under-custom-folder-without-changing-wp-config-php-or-ch) . I think this topic has been create multiple time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the question is a little different...

Comment: But check the answer .. it starts by "Here is simple function to create your own sub directory for every upload.". Seems good for your question.

Comment: I tried function awesome_wallpaper_dir( $param ){
    $mydir = '/onixion';

    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir;
    $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir;

    return $param;
}

add_filter( 'upload_dir', array( $this, 'awesome_wallpaper_dir' ) ); but I'm getting an error...

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /Users/mac/Desktop/localhost4/wp-content/plugins/onixion/onixion.php on line 220 (the line where add_filter is)

Comment: I didn't see first time but you add `$this` in your filter. You are not in an object so just do that : copy paste awesome_wallpaper_dir( $param ){ 
    $mydir = '/onixion'; 
    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir; $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir; return $param; 
} 
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'awesome_wallpaper_dir')

Comment: Actually, it works with $this. It's all in a class. add_filter was misplaced... Now it works, but I have to remove 2018/10 folder... because my example folder is in 2018/10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
public function onixion_custom_dir_upload_function( $param ){ $mydir = '../../../example'; $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir; $param['url'] = $param['url'] 
. $mydir; return $param; } 

add_filter( 'upload_dir', array( $this, 'onixion_custom_dir_upload_function' ) 
);
```

It creates a folder example in the uploads folder, and stores uploaded files there.

If you're not in a class, you don't need

```
array( $this, 'onixion_custom_dir_upload_function' )
```

just write:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'onixion_custom_dir_upload_function');
```

If someone have same needs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code

```
$target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '../../example' .
```

Try this code. This code will change your upload directory path. 
I have used this to upload file in my custom folder in Upload Directory.

```
$target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target_file = $target_dir['basedir'].'/example'.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... I got the same result. The file is being named examplefilename.ext...

Comment: Can you please share the Full Code if possible so that I can debug it ?

Comment: I solved it... kinda... now there is an folder, but in uploads/2018/10... now just need to remove 2018/10 folder...